# Android studio configure command line properties

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

While release builds I am setting this property -PsomeVariable="C:\Users\bchichani\signing.pem" through command line.

Need to know how to configure android studio so that it set this every time runs gradle build even for debug builds.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines (replacing the paths with the ones correct for your computer) to 'gradle.properties':

someVariable=C:/Users/bchichani/signing.pem